# Excel 2010 - How to compare columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have 2 columns (A & B) with over 16k rows of data in each column.

Column `A` has 80 rows more than column `B`. They both should be the same number of rows.

How do I compare the two columns to see what fell off on column B? Column B will have names that aren't in Column A. I want to compare column A to ensure that all the names are in column B.

Example:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Column A           |     Column B        |
--------------------------------------------
| Abdeljawa,Mohammed | ABDELJAWA MOHAMMED  |
| Abdella,Georgette  | ABDELLA GEORGETTE   |
| Abdul,Moiz M       | ABDELLA ZIAD        |
| Abdullahi,Abukar   | ABDUL MOIZ MOSHEEN  |
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: 1) The two columns are supposed to have the same number of rows.  But if B contains names not in A, not all A names can be in B even if 80 rows weren't missing.  So much of your question seems like over-complicating distraction.  2) Even the matching names don't necessarily match, beyond case and punctuation.  Abdul, Moiz M is not identical to case-corrected, punctuation-corrected Abdul Moiz Mosheen.  You don't describe the potential range of differences, or whether only the A name can be a shortened version of the B name.  So you can't use a simple lookup.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy answer:**

In cell `C1` enter the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)
```

and drag it down column `C` till the end of the data in column `B`.

This way you are comparing each value in column `B` to check if they are in column `A` (looking for an **exact** match for values).

---

**Digging deeper...**

Based on the sample data that you have provided, it looks like the same name in column `A` could appear differently in column `B`.

The three things that I noticed are:

- Capitalization (all UPPERCASE versus Sentence Case)
- Punctuation (addition of a comma instead of a space)
- Order (such as FirstName *[space]* LastName vs LastName,FirstName *[space]* Middle Initial)

If you also want to handle these situations while looking up if column `B` has everything in column `A`, then you would need to get a bit more involved.

It could be that you only want to consider some of these inconsistencies (if any) depending on the number of occurrences of the each one.

I will address each of the inconsistencies in the data separately. Depending on which ones you need you take into consideration, you can nest them as needed.

**Capitalization:** Excel's `VLOOKUP` function is case insensitive. So this shouldn't be a problem if you are using `VLOOKUP` to look for data. But if you are using a different function, capitalization is an easy one to handle. What you would need to do it convert **all** of your data to either lowercase or UPPERCASE so that it's consistent. (I personally prefer UPPERCASE for reasons that I really don't know)

- To convert data to lowercase, use the [LOWER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOWER-function-3f21df02-a80c-44b2-afaf-81358f9fdeb4)
- To convert data to UPPERCASE, use the [UPPER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-c11f29b3-d1a3-4537-8df6-04d0049963d6)

Note: you could also use the [Proper function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PROPER-function-52a5a283-e8b2-49be-8506-b2887b889f94) to convert everything to Proper Case as well if you wish to.

You can use these functions and create 2 new columns of data with consistent capitalization or you could use them within a formula to convert values on the fly.

Punctuation: Based on the sample you have provided, there was an instance where one in column `A`, the names were separated by a comma and the same name was separated by a space. If there are many such instances, you could stick to one format by using the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332).

For example if you want to remove all commas in cell `A1` and replace them with a space, you could use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ")
```

Again similar to capitalization, you can have 2 new columns with the results of substitution or you can use them within any other formula as well. This is how the `VLOOKUP` formula would look if you wanted to remove the comma in cell `A1` and replace it with a space before looking it up in column `B`:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),B:B,1,FALSE)
```

Order: If the order of the same name is different in column `A` and column `B`, and there are a lot of such instances, you might have to consider reordering names before looking them up. This can get really complex easily so:

1. Make sure there is a significant amount of data that needs to be reordered before doing this.
2. Make sure that the same name is ordered differently in the 2 columns in a **consistent** way.
3. If there is data like this among correctly matching data, do this only on data for which there are no matches.

To reorder a name in a cell from LastName, Firstname to FirstName LastName, see below.

Taken from [How can I switch a string from “lastName, firstName” to “firstName LastName”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331358/how-can-i-switch-a-string-from-lastname-firstname-to-firstname-lastname):

> If the first name is in A2 try this formula in B2 copied down
>
> =MID(A2&" "&A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-1)

If you want to switch the ordering of the names the other way around, and/or consider the middle initial when reordering, you can use the functions [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c), [RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f), [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028), [LEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEN-LENB-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb), [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) as needed to do that as well.

One last thing, depending on how the data got to the Excel file, you *may* need to perform other [data cleanup functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Top-ten-ways-to-clean-your-data-2844b620-677c-47a7-ac3e-c2e157d1db19) such as [CLEAN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CLEAN-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [TRIM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, here is one:

Put in column C a  formula that takes each value of column A and searches it in column B; if not found, flag it. Then put a filter on the flag; that way you can easily see the differences.

The formula would look like (Cell C1):
`=VLOOKUP(A1,B$1:B$20000,1,FALSE)`
This will put the value from A into C if it also exists in B and `#ERROR` if not.

Then copy the formula down, and filter C for `#ERROR`, you will see all A values that are missing from B.

If you have - as in your examples - slight differences in your spelling, that is not enough; you need to use `UPPER(A1)` in stead of `A1` to make them match, and if you have those commas in there too, you need to add a replace `','` by nothing.

Comment: This will give false positives since there are more differences than just capitalization and punctuation, like Abdul, Moiz M is not identical to case-corrected, punctuation-corrected Abdul Moiz Mosheen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VLOOKUP formula to determine which col A values do not appear in col B. Paste the formula below into the first cell of an empty column then copy it all the way down. If a cell returns #N/A, then the col A value in that row does not appear in col B.

Note that col B must be sorted in descending order. If you don't want to reorder your data for some reason, just copy it onto a different sheet and sort it there.

> =VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)

Comment: This will give false positives since there are more differences than just capitalization and punctuation, like Abdul, Moiz M is not identical to case-corrected, punctuation-corrected Abdul Moiz Mosheen.

Comment: I see, yes. Bu the number should be small, and there is no way for any function in Excel to know if `... M` is the same guy as `... Mosheen`. It's probably still as good as it can be.

Comment: Another option would be to copy it all into a single column then use the duplicate tools to highlight or delete anything that shows up twice.

Comment: This formula in the current revision of the answer (`=VLOOKUP(A1,B,1,FALSE`) is not correct. The 2nd parameter (`table_array`) is incorrect. It needs to be a range. I have included the correct one in my answer along with possible data cleanup functions that could be used to overcome any significant inconsistencies in data

Comment: Good catch. I'll be sure to fix and give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The matter is pretty complicated given that Column A has commas in it while Column B doesn't, and Column B is in all caps while Column A isn't.  What I would do personally is load each column into separate text files, and then use the Linux utility sed to get rid of the comma and change to all upper case in the first file.  Then I could just run the diff utility.

Comment: As soon as you hit the first mismatch, everything after that will not match.  So it could be that virtually the entire list is in the diff utility.  Since you aren't working with the source data, you can't fix a row and see the impact.  You need to repeat your whole process to find the next actual mismatch.  This would be an extremely inefficient process that would be greatly improved working directly with the source data.

Answer (score 0):

FoThis going to be little tricky since names are not in the same format. One way to do this is make a column to the right that does a compare, starting in d2

- =IF( UPPER(TRIM(LEFT(A2,5)))=UPPER(TRIM(LEFT(B2,5))),D3,ROW())

What this does is give you the row of the next miscompare (the row number bubbles up). when find one, correct or add a blank into appropriate column

Then continue with next one.

The purpose of this approach may not be clear. Since know there are less than 100 expected issues, it is of the right size for a quick & dirty. Find a issue, move to the next one. etc. then  done.  If the expected # of errors was larger, a different approach would be used.

This approach uses a re-cycle instead of everything fix in one go approach.  Find 1 problem, fix 1 problem, then go to the next problem, then next , etc. until everything addressed. The focus is on getting into the right area quickly. By having the row number can jump straight to next. if 1205 was next issue, a ctrl-g for A1205 jumps straight to next issue.  The formula will not accurately show all issues, as once the rows are off 1 from one having more data, almost all compares will fail.  This is a quick way to find your first problem, fix it, then move on to the next problem.

I suspect questioner will have more problems than was stated. Additional problems can be found using the same formula approach by modifying the test portion of the if statement.

Comment: what part did not get addressed?

Comment: Saying it addresses one piece wasn't really accurate.  This doesn't seem to address the question.  The question's example shows two pairs of names that match in the 1st five letters, so this approach would have a high likelihood of failing to catch mismatched names.  It will also repeat mismatching row identities on the preceding matching line.  It isn't clear what duplicating the row number in the wrong place buys you.

Answer (score 0):

my english is bad but I hope that I'll list below to help

at the beginning of :
the name in cell switched to more cells with text to data fun.
 example 
Cell1 = Abdul,Moiz M
Cell3 = Abdul
Cell4 = Moiz
Cell5 = M
And
Cell2 = ABDUL MOIZ MOSHEEN
Cell6 = ABDUL 
Cell7 = MOIZ
Cell8 = MOSHEEN

Them you UPPER cells 2,3,4,6,7,8

And with MATCH fun count number of    matching for cells  2,3,4,6,7,8, and two and more matching are a good result with a small probability failures.